# ActiveX component installation is blocked by IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, com, activex, interop

HI

I have created a ActiveX componed and packed into a cab file

1)  Created the setup for Class Library that I would like to be exposed for COM access.
2)  Create the CAB setup project taking the Project output from the setup created in the setup 1.
3)  Embedded the object tag in a sample html file

Now when I launch the sample html from IE, it is showing an security alert, when I accept the security waning the installation was blocked with the following message.

"winows has blocked this software because it can't verify the publisher"

thanking you.

Comment: i have modified the security settings of the browser also by following the link
http://www.windowsreference.com/internet-explorer/windows-has-blocked-this-software-because-it-cant-verify-the-publisher/
But no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [sign your ActiveX control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974305.aspx).

Comment: same issue is coming.

eventhough i signed cab file with singntool available in microsoft sdks.